# Use regular expression in Swift String.contains() func

Tags: swift

In Swift, I have a String Variable `thisString`. I want to check to make sure the string contains only letters, numbers and/or dashes (-). Aside from doing this:

```
if ( thisString.contains("$") || thisString.contains("%") ) {
  //reject
} else {
 //accept
}
```

for each undesired character, which is ridiculous. I can't figure it out.

I would like to, in theory, do something like this with a regular expression:

```
if ( thisString.contains(regex([^a-zA-Z0-9-]) ) { 
  //reject
} else {
  //accept
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You just forgot the capital "R". It now works, JerseyDevil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are quite close

```
if thisString.range(of: "[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", options: .regularExpression) != nil { 
  //reject
} else {
  //accept
}
```

Update:

It becomes much more convenient with the new Swift Regex syntax (available in Swift 5.7+) where the syntax is pretty close to what you are looking for

```
if thisString.contains(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/) { 
  //reject
} else {
  //accept
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a set of characters and check if it is a superset of your string. It is much faster than using regex.

```
let validCharacters: Set = .init("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-")

let string1 = "Lkabo-1"
let string2 = "Lkabo-2!"

if validCharacters.isSuperset(of: string1) {
    print(true)  // true
} else {
    print(false)
}
if validCharacters.isSuperset(of: string2) {
    print(true)
} else {
    print(false)  // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSPredicate` with `String` extension.

```
extension String {
    enum ValidationType: String {
        case alphabet = "[A-Za-z]+"
        case alphabetWithSpace = "[A-Za-z ]*"
        case alphabetNum = "[A-Za-z-0-9]*"
        case alphabetNumWithDash = "[A-Za-z-0-9\-]*"
    }
    
    func isValid(_ type: ValidationType) -> Bool {
        guard !isEmpty else { return false }
        let regTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", type.rawValue)
        return regTest.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
thisString.isValid(.alphabetNumWithDash)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now simply use `.contains` with a regex.

```
print(try! "example".contains(Regex("[^a-z]") ))

print(try! "example".contains(Regex("[A-Z]") ))
```

etc.

Indeed, you can even just

```
if s.contains( /[AEIOU]/ ) { print("has a big vowel") }

if !s.contains( /[^a-z]/ ) { print("syntax error") }
```

Comment: `[AEIOU]` would return false for  `"aeiou"`

Comment: Btw you can simply use Character properties like `isLowercase` and keyPath syntax like `contains(where: \.isLowercase)`. This is much preferred as it contains all possible locale variations. If you need to check the opposite `extension Bool {` `var negated: Bool { !self }` `}` and do `contains(where: \.isLowercase.negated)`

Comment: Isn't `if !s.contains( /[^a-z]/ )` true when `s` *is* lowercase? You are saying "if s doesn't contain any non-lowercase letters" - that will be true when s only contains lowercase letters.

Comment: hi @HangarRash !   ?  yes obviously. (As programmers, surely "!  /[^a-z]/" means more than some sentence in English or another language :) )

Comment: cheers @LeoDabus I suppose that would be preferred in some situations, maybe if dealing with human input or such?  Anyway, while that is a great general tip for anyone googling here, the question at hand was "What's the syntax I'm looking for here .. thisString.contains(regex([^a-zA-Z0-9-])"